# Cancelling a DisplaySettingsChanged Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I have some trouble with the DisplaySettingsChanged event. I want to cancel it when it tries to rotate the screen on the tablet.
The problem is that it takes an EventArgs parameter, which doesn't have any Cancel property.

How can I pass through this and cancel this event anyway ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing which platform you are targetting it is difficult to help, but have you had a look at this if you're developing for Windows 8\ Windows Phone 8.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.autorotationpreferences

Did you have a look at the following example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Auto-Rotation-Preferences-87ae2902

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to mention that. I indeed am developping on a tablet which is running on windows 8.1.
The fact is, i already wanted to use that method but didn't succed at all. Is there specific things to do to use that method ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to an MS example, this might help

Comment: Well thank you for that, had no clue until i read it was a windows store app.